# Microsoft visual studio run time library error in Qgis 1.8

Tags: qgis, windows, visual-studio

I am using QGIS 1.8.

When I open my QGIS project, I get an error from Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library: Runtime Error! For other machine its working fine.Since I have uninstalled and re-installed the QGIS,but still same problem.

What can I do for fixing this?

OS: Windows XP SP2

Answer (score 2):

Most probably a version conflict of different VC runtime versions. You can de-install them separately in System -> Software. I would also suggest to install SP3 for XP.